# Digital voltmeter ammeter wrong reading

Tags: power-supply, buck, voltmeter

Hello! I've built a small adjustable PSU with a buck converter (XL4015 module) and a cheap 10A digital voltmeter and ammeter. It worked fine for a few minutes but after that the voltmeter started fluctuating between the real voltage and something like half of that, most of the time showing the wrong value.

I've wired it following a schematic on the internet, but powered the voltmeter from the input of the buck converter (where as in the schematic the red -meter power- and yellow -Vsense- wire where connected) because the output will go as low as 1.5V, not being able to power the meter. I've tested the meter separately and confirmed that the problem is related to it. I do have a spare one, but I don't want to do the same thing with it. Is the wiring correct? Is there any chance I could fix the meter?
[image: Schematic]
(edit:) Sorry for the lack of details, it was my first post.
Links:

- [10A Voltmeter Ammeter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-DC-100V-10A-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Blue-Red-LED-Amp-Dual-Digital-Volt-Meter-Gauge/32814017487.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.8xBb9m)
- [Buck Converter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5A-Lithium-Charger-Step-down-5A-5V-32V-to-0-8V-30V-Power-Supply-Module-LED/32651786894.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.uSijC1)

The shunt is connected to the thick black and red wires. And I've let the thin black disconnected because It's common with the thick one.

Comment: The meter module will have a shunt resistor to measure the current. It is unclear how that resistor is connected in relation to the supply voltage input and voltage measurement input of the meter. This information is crucial as it will dictate how the meter should be connected. You might have to do some reverse engineering here as these modules usually have no proper technical documentation.

Comment: Show the correct circuit if you want any help. Link the devices too because nobody here can read minds.

Comment: The wire pair connecting between the output and input of the converter seem suspect, though this cannot be confirmed unless you include the V/A module's part number or a link to the documentation.

Comment: where is the DVM datasheet or spec.?

Comment: Is the Black power supply on the meter (the one on the bottom) really left unconnected like it is drawn here? I'd strongly suggest connecting that to Vin black as well. Otherwise it is powered god knows how. But then I'm just applying my logic, which could be way off without a datasheet.

Comment: Yes I fail to understand how the voltmeter itself gets power for its own operation.  Does it have a battery?  Listen to @Arsenal.  Ok I  see the meter powers itself between its red and black.  You need to put meter power there.  It senses voltage between yellow and black, not yellow and red.

Comment: @Flav, Also note that a current shunt is normally only needed when measuring very high currents.

Comment: You have the shunt on the wrong side of the load. The shunt has to be on the low side.

Comment: But I want to measure the output voltage of the buck converter, thus I assumed the shunt would be connected on the top.

Comment: @Flav The shunt measures the current, not the voltage and it's on the low side (if you want it to function).

Comment: I know that. But let's leave the shunt aside for now. The problem is with the voltage measurement. Or I think with the meter altogether.

Comment: @Flav "the voltmeter started fluctuating between the real voltage and something like half of that" makes me think that either the voltage *is* fluctuating or there is a loose connection somewhere, perhaps in the soldering of the components on the meter's PCB.

Comment: I don't think so. I've tested it with a multimeter as well and I've made sure the connections were secure.

Comment: I just used it with XL6009 buck-boost converter, connected in a same way as you, and it's working fine. [XL6009 buck-boost power source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSvoo.jpg)

Comment: Does the problem go away if you load your power supply with a moderate load (say 100mA)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have something close to this type of V/A meter, 
[https://www.amazon.com/Paddsun-Digital-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Meter/dp/B01LSGP1UI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LSGP1UI)

in which case the proper wiring connections are included on the left side of the amazon page.

Notably the thin red and black wires are the modules power inputs, while the yellow is the voltage sense contact. The wiring method depends on if you want the meter powered from the source power or the output power.

Comment: That's how I wanted to wire it, with a common power adapter. But the meter works above 4V, while the output of the buck goes as low as 1.5v. So I can't connect both of them to the output of the converter.

Comment: It's ok to have 1.5V between yellow and black.  What you must have is 4V+ between red and black.  There is no rule that says you must connect yellow and red to the same place.

Comment: That's what I assumed when I connected them like that, but something went wrong apparently. I know cheap electronics from china aren't always reliable, but I don't think it's that.

Comment: An external current shunt (if needed) would be connected across the meter's thick red and black wires.  But per the spec I see that an external shunt is only needed if measuring >10A.

Comment: I'll only be measuring a maximum of 5A, so the included one (a thick copper wire on the meter circuit pretty much) connected between the wires you've specified will work fine.

Comment: Is the meter working with your updated wiring?  As you stated the 0-10A shunt included on the meter should be the one used.  Also, if you are using tinned or solid wires in the converter's screw down terminals the mixing of thick and thin wires might at times leave the thin wire loose or disconnected.

Comment: The updated wiring is the same, just connected the black thin wire to gnd, which was also done through the thick black one. And I also wired it separately to only measure voltage and it still doesn't show a correct measurement.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these amp volt panel meters have knock off 3.3volt voltage regulators to power the meter. I had a number fail if powered over 12volts. I think its an a1117 regulator. If you have wired it wrong you also may have blown a resister to the meter and the regulator. Changing the reg out normally fixes a dead meter.